# One pushpin click opens them all

Tags: bing, bing-maps

Need help troubleshooting. All of the pushpins open upon clicking a single one opens up every pushpin infobox. I want there to be one pushpin infobox that changes each time a pushpin is clicked, only allowing one infobox to be open at a time.

```
            // BING MAP Java Script    
            var map = null;
            var pinid = 0;
            var arrPinInfobox = [];
            //Bing V8 start
            function GetMap() { //LocInfo, Lat, Long
                var _MapElement = document.getElementById("myMap");
                if (_MapElement === null || typeof _MapElement === "undefined")
                    return;
                if(jQuery("#pagesitemap_4_noMap").length < 0)
                    return;
                var arrLocInfoRec = [];
                var arrLLAdder = [];
                var MapCenterLat;
                var MapCenterLong;
                var ZoomFactor;
                var ZipLLSource = jQuery("#hdnZipLL").val();
                var LocInfo = jQuery("#hdnCompleteLocInfo").val();
                var ZipLL = [];
                var Lat = "";
                var Long ="";
                console.log("Long");
                if(typeof LocInfo === "undefined")
                { 
                    console.log("locInfo Undefined");
                      return;
                }
                if (ZipLLSource.length > 0) {
                    ZipLL = (ZipLLSource).split("`");
                }
                if (LocInfo.length > 0) {
                    arrLocInfoRec = LocInfo.split("|")
                }
                if (Lat.length > 0 && Long.length > 0) {
                    MapCenterLat = parseFloat(Lat);
                    MapCenterLong = parseFloat(Long);
                    ZoomFactor = 11;  //16
                }
                else if (ZipLL.length >= 2) {
                    MapCenterLat = parseFloat(ZipLL[0]);
                    MapCenterLong = parseFloat(ZipLL[1]);
                    ZoomFactor = 11;
                }
                var mapOptions = {
                    credentials: '                       ',
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(MapCenterLat, MapCenterLong),
                    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.Automatic,
                    zoom: ZoomFactor,
                    showScalebar: true
                }
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', mapOptions);
                var arrPins = [];
                var arrPinCenter = [];
                //Generating Pins for multiple locations with Lat,Long
                for (var locNum = 0; locNum <= arrLocInfoRec.length - 1; locNum++) {
                    try {
                        arrLLAdder = arrLocInfoRec[locNum].split("`");
                        if (arrLLAdder.length >= 13) {
                            //var latlong = arrLLAdder[11].split(',');
                            arrPinCenter[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(arrLLAdder[11]), parseFloat(arrLLAdder[12]));
                            arrPinCenter[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(arrLLAdder[11]), parseFloat(arrLLAdder[12]));
                            arrPins[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(
                                                                            arrPinCenter[locNum], { 
                                                                                                    text: arrLLAdder[8] ,
                                                                                                    icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',
                                                                                                    anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(12, 39) 
                                                                                                     }
                                                                        );
                            var adder = arrLLAdder[2] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[4] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[6] + arrLLAdder[9] + "\r\n" + arrLLAdder[1]
                            // Create the infobox for the pushpin
                            arrPinInfobox[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(arrPins[locNum].getLocation(),
                                {   width: 350,
                                    height: 100,
                                    title: arrLLAdder[5],
                                    description: adder,
                                    offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-3,13),
                                    visible: false
                                });     
                            // Add handler for the pushpin click event.                       
                            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(arrPins[locNum], 'click', displayInfobox);
                            // Add the Push Pins and InfoBox to the map all at once                         
                             if(arrPins.length > 0) {
                                map.entities.push(arrPins); //[locNum]
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Invalid Data: arrLocInfoRec[" + locNum + "] = \"" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum] + "\"");
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e.message + "\r\n" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum]);
                    }
                }      
            }
            function displayInfobox(e) {
                //map.entities.push(arrPinInfobox);
                console.log("DisplayBox");
                for(var i in arrPinInfobox){
                arrPinInfobox[i].setOptions({ visible: true });
                arrPinInfobox[parseInt(e.target.getText()) - 1].setOptions({ visible: true });
                var infobox = arrPinInfobox[i];
                infobox.setMap(map);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the displayInfobox function loops through all your infoboxes and sets visible to true and adding them to the map. Your code is functioning how it was written.

What you want to do is filter out your infoboxes. Personally I hate the whole array of infobox idea, it is messy. I believe I've recommended before the idea of creating a single infobox and reusing it when a pushpin is clicked. That is the best approach if you only need one infobox to appear at a time. If you want to be able to show multiple infoboxes at a time, store the reference to the infobox in the pushpin some how. All shapes in Bing Maps has a metadata property reserved for your custom data. Also just noticed you add the array of pushpins to the map several times, this will cause issues. Here is a proposed change to your code, I've added a comment with // Ricky: to indicate the changes I made:

```
// BING MAP Java Script    
var map = null;
var pinid = 0;
var arrPinInfobox = [];
//Bing V8 start
function GetMap() { //LocInfo, Lat, Long
    var _MapElement = document.getElementById("myMap");
    if (_MapElement === null || typeof _MapElement === "undefined")
        return;
    if(jQuery("#pagesitemap_4_noMap").length < 0)
        return;
    var arrLocInfoRec = [];
    var arrLLAdder = [];
    var MapCenterLat;
    var MapCenterLong;
    var ZoomFactor;
    var ZipLLSource = jQuery("#hdnZipLL").val();
    var LocInfo = jQuery("#hdnCompleteLocInfo").val();
    var ZipLL = [];
    var Lat = "";
    var Long ="";
    console.log("Long");
    if(typeof LocInfo === "undefined")
    { 
        console.log("locInfo Undefined");
          return;
    }
    if (ZipLLSource.length > 0) {
        ZipLL = (ZipLLSource).split("`");
    }
    if (LocInfo.length > 0) {
        arrLocInfoRec = LocInfo.split("|")
    }
    if (Lat.length > 0 && Long.length > 0) {
        MapCenterLat = parseFloat(Lat);
        MapCenterLong = parseFloat(Long);
        ZoomFactor = 11;  //16
    }
    else if (ZipLL.length >= 2) {
        MapCenterLat = parseFloat(ZipLL[0]);
        MapCenterLong = parseFloat(ZipLL[1]);
        ZoomFactor = 11;
    }
    var mapOptions = {
        credentials: '                       ',
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(MapCenterLat, MapCenterLong),
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.Automatic,
        zoom: ZoomFactor,
        showScalebar: true
    }
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', mapOptions);
    var arrPins = [];
    var arrPinCenter = [];

    //Generating Pins for multiple locations with Lat,Long
    for (var locNum = 0; locNum <= arrLocInfoRec.length - 1; locNum++) {
        try {
            arrLLAdder = arrLocInfoRec[locNum].split("`");
            if (arrLLAdder.length >= 13) {
                //var latlong = arrLLAdder[11].split(',');
                arrPinCenter[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(arrLLAdder[11]), parseFloat(arrLLAdder[12]));

                arrPins[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(arrPinCenter[locNum], { 
                                        text: arrLLAdder[8] ,
                                        icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',
                                        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(12, 39) 
                                         });

                var adder = arrLLAdder[2] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[4] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[6] + arrLLAdder[9] + "\r\n" + arrLLAdder[1]
                // Create the infobox for the pushpin
                //Ricky: Add your infobox as a reference in your pushpin
                arrPins[locNum]. metadata = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(arrPins[locNum].getLocation(),
                    {   width: 350,
                        height: 100,
                        title: arrLLAdder[5],
                        description: adder,
                        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-3,13),
                        visible: false
                    });     

                // Add handler for the pushpin click event.                       
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(arrPins[locNum], 'click', displayInfobox);             
            }
            else {
                console.log("Invalid Data: arrLocInfoRec[" + locNum + "] = \"" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum] + "\"");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message + "\r\n" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum]);
        }
    }

    // Add the Push Pins and InfoBox to the map all at once                         
    //Ricky: Moved this out of the array as you only need to add array of pushpins to the map once.
    if(arrPins.length > 0) {
        map.entities.push(arrPins); //[locNum]
    }   
}
function displayInfobox(e) {
    //map.entities.push(arrPinInfobox);
    console.log("DisplayBox");

    //Get infobox from the pushpin, rather than looping through array.
    var infobox = e.target.metadata;
    infobox.setOptions({ visible: true });

    //for(var i in arrPinInfobox){
        //arrPinInfobox[i].setOptions({ visible: true });
        //arrPinInfobox[parseInt(e.target.getText()) - 1].setOptions({ visible: true });
        //var infobox = arrPinInfobox[i];
        //infobox.setMap(map);
    //}
}
```

If you want to clean up your code some more I recommend:

- get rid of all the array's, there is no need for them.
- Use a layer for your pushpins. Add a single click event on the layer rather than on each individual pushpin.